# How can I scroll up one line in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I'm using iTerm2 w/ bash and I scroll up through the history buffer one line by typing `Shift+Up`.  When I switch to my zsh shell, it just inputs `2A`.  How can I scroll up a single line in zsh w/ just my keyboard, preferably using `Shift+Up`?

Answer (score 6):

I think it depends from the terminal emulator.

For example, with *zsh*, in konsole it works <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.
In xterm not, but it works <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

It seems that with iTerm2 it should work by default :

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> to move one line up
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> to move one line down

Comment: In ZSH in Arch Linux inside Virtualbox inside Windows 8, it was Shift+PgUp

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is provided by the `up-history` and `up-line-or-history` widgets (`down-history` and `down-line-or-history` for scrolling down).

By default `up-line-or-history` should be bound to <kbd>Up</kbd> but you can bind it to (almost) any other key sequence with `bindkey`. In terminals special keys (keys that do not generate a printable character) generate a sequence of keys that is then interpreted by the shell - or not, as your example of `2A` for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> shows. These key sequences also may differ between terminal emulators. In order to get the correct key sequence for your terminal, open it, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by the key combination you want (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>). On my terminal (rxvt-unicode) I get `^[[a`. You can then bind the sequence to the `up-history` widged:

```
bindkey <in-string> up-history
```

Just replace `<in-string>` with the found sequence. In my case

```
bindkey '^[[a' up-history
```

**Note 1:** You most likely need to put the sequence in quotes as it probably will contain characters that will be interpreted by `zsh` otherwise.

**Note 2:** Some key combinations may generate identical key sequences. For example, letters combined with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> usually do not differ from the same letters combined with just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Both, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> usually produce `^A`. In some terminal emulators <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combinations are even used for shortcuts of the terminal itself and are not available in the shell.